# Display text from CKEditor

Tags: php, text, ckeditor

When I display CKEditor text the html tags are also displayed. How can I only show the text?
I'm getting this:

> <p> &nbsp;</p> <ul style="list-style-type:
>   none; list-style-image: none; list-style-position: outside;">
>   <li> Nurzahan Road,Dhaka</li> <li> West of Tajmahal
>   Road</li> <li> Phone: 9110614</li> </ul>

I want to show only this:

```
* Nurzahan Road,Dhaka
* West of Tajmahal Road
* Phone: 9110614
```

Comment: you may clarify if you are starting from an escaped or not-escaped string and what you want to get (plain text, not-escaped or escaped text, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably a `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` somewhere in the code that displays the HTML code. If you put in the HTML as you quoted it into a HTML page, it should turn up as desired.

Comment: hi pekka,

this is the line used to print 

<? echo $data[contact];?>

Comment: Where does that variable come from? A database?

Comment: You could try `echo html_entity_decode($data["contact"]);` for a quick fix but you should really clarify where your data comes from, so somebody can recommend a clean solution.

Comment: thanks a lot man...
echo html_entity_decode($data["contact"]); this works fine. data is coming from db.

Comment: You're welcome, but it would be really better to find out why the code goes into the database entitie()d, it shouldn't do that in the first place.

Comment: We can't answer that because we don't know what code you use to save it to the database. I think it would merit another question of its own, though.