# Converting text from HTML to MS Word

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word

I'm trying to convert HTML (From CK Editor) to MS Word:

```
wordDoc = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
```

But the result shows all HTML tags (like `span`, `strong`) in the Word document.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895795/getting-non-html-text-from-ckeditor

Comment: if you can make well formed XHTML out of the CK Editor output, and are comfortable using Java, then docx4j may help.

Comment: fun fact: if you rename a file named test.html to test.doc, and it's a complete HTML document, double-clicking the file will open it in word as expected, formatting, WYSIWYG and all.

Comment: It matters what version of MS Word you are targeting. @dandavis is correct if your users are on > 2007.

Answer (score 0):

There are some complete solutions for your problem. Try these ones:

- http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/
- http://www.phpdocx.com/
- http://phpword.codeplex.com/
- http://www.phplivedocx.org/articles/brief-introduction-to-phplivedocx/

Answer (score 0):

While you're looking for a WORD solution, could a PDF solution work as well?  Try http://www.fpdf.org if so.  But again this doesn't work if you absolutely must have WORD as the end result.  Unless you need the user to type on the document, PDFs are generally better as they prevent a user from modifying.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question i understand that you want HTML to Word With All Style(Css Apply)

i have such requirenmnet i had implement below code it's perfactly work for me. please check below code may be it's help full to you

here i am create  Word File from GridView and i had apply Style to that grid.it's create same Grid in Word file as it display in browser.you need to only change style (css) related tag for your work.

```
Protected Sub CreateHTMlToWord()
        Try

            Dim sHtml As New StringBuilder
            Dim htmlForm As New HtmlForm
            grdHTMLData.GridLines = GridLines.Both 'Grid View Fill with data

            Response.ClearContent()
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=estPage.doc")
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.doc"

            Dim str As New IO.StringWriter
            Dim htex As New HtmlTextWriter(str)
            htmlForm.Controls.Add(grdHTMLData)
            htmlForm.EnableViewState = False
            Me.Controls.Add(htmlForm)
            htmlForm.RenderControl(htex)

            sHtml.Append("<html>")
            sHtml.Append("<head>")
            sHtml.Append("<style type='text/css'>")
            sHtml.Append(".mGrid{width: 100%; background-color: #F8FCFE; margin: 5px 0 10px 0; border-collapse: collapse;}")
            sHtml.Append(".mGrid td{ padding: 2px; color: black;} .mGrid td a:link{ color: #000;}")
            sHtml.Append(".mGrid th{ padding: 4px 2px; color: #fff; background: #4A7298; font-size: 0.9em;}")
            sHtml.Append(".mGrid th a:link{ color: #fff; font-weight: bold;} .mGrid .alt{ background-color: #E1EEF7;}")
            sHtml.Append(".mGrid .pgr{ background: #E1EEF7;} .mGrid .pgr table{ margin: 5px 0;}")
            sHtml.Append(".mGrid .pgr td span{ border-width: 0; font-weight: bold; color: #666; line-height: 12px;}")
            sHtml.Append(".mGrid .pgr td a{ color: #666;} .mGrid .pgr td a:link{ color: #4A7298; padding: 0 5px; text-decoration: underline;}")
            sHtml.Append(".mGrid .pgr td a:active{ text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold;}")
            sHtml.Append(".mGrid .pgr td a:hover{ color: #fff; background-color: #4A7298; text-decoration: none;} .mGrid a:hover{ text-decoration: underline;}")
            sHtml.Append(".mGridHdr th{ text-align: left;}")
            sHtml.Append("</style>")
            sHtml.Append("</head>")
            sHtml.Append("<body>")
            sHtml.Append(str.ToString)
            sHtml.Append("</body>")
            sHtml.Append("</html>")

            Response.Write(sHtml.ToString)
            Response.Flush()
            Response.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/%22pandoc%22) allows conversion between html and word documents (among many other formats).
Pandoc is an haskel library but there are bundled installer for all platform. To convert your document you will need to use this command.

```
pandoc -o file.doc file.html
```

Answer (score 0):

What I could imagine is like following steps:

1. Translates your HTML into OpenXML,
2. then create the files corresponding to the structure of the word document,
3. Zip into docx.